# So what if the nature of Dasein is Being-in?

Tags: heidegger, being-and-time

I am new to Heidegger. I've just made some preliminary sense of what an existentiale is supposed to be (I am taking it as ontological elements of Dasein's being, core things that are possibility conditions for other things) and I've just understood that Being-in is supposed to be an existentiale.

My question now is - so what? What are interesting consequences of this realisation?

Answer (score 1):

Some folk see being as participating in consensus reality.  However, the perspective that come from seeing perception originating from your existential bio-being reveals that you're actually only seeing the inside of your own mind, (except when one occasionally receives some cogent information from outside).

It's akin to Descates' phenomenological perspective, but adds the basic existential entity; then the point is to analyse the type of being that the Dasein has, because it may not be what you thought it was.

One of the outcomes is consideration of where being is coming from.  It isn't thrust upon you for you to conform to.  It *is* you and yours to own (enown).  Owning your being, like Nietzsche's *amor fati*.  Subtle shifts in attitude.  ('Inceptual thinking': starting again, in a different direction.)

The ordinary language of the world tends to do the opposite.  It cultivates consensus reality and constraining worldviews.

More here: *Contributions to Philosophy,* [*The human being and Da-sein*](https://books.google.gg/books?id=nMupXLZd8s4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA251#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Bringing together these threads via a comment on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heideggerian_terminology#Care_(or_concern)): "All these ways of Being-in have concern (Sorge, care) as their kind of Being."

And elaborating with an opening quote from *Contributions*, page 16:

> In this manner the inceptual meditation of thought necessarily becomes
> genuine thought, which is to say, *goal*-positing thought. ...
>
> To be *seeker, preserver, steward* -- that is what is meant by *care*
> as the fundamental trait of Dasein. These names for care gather
> together the destiny of humans as grasped in terms of their ground,
> i.e., in terms of Da-sein.  Da-sein, in turning, is ap-propriated to
> the *event* as the essence of beyng, and only in virtue of this origin
> as the grounding of time-space ("primordial temporality") can Da-sein
> become steadfast in order to transform the plight of the abandonment by
> being into the necessity of creating as the restoring of being.

So in this quote there is 'inceptual' thinking again, appropriation (owning), and a focus on care, being careful, (skilled, being masterful), as every empowerment intrinsically requires.  This is contrast to a disempowered (abandoned) way.

This is the attitude shift that is the "interesting consequence" of this realisation.