# The formal philosophy as a habit

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, life

**I am a Computer Science Student**, I have always loved **philosophy** and the way it makes the obvious  logical , But sad to say I struggle with learning it and studying it in my life, Because philosophy has its own terms and methods to express ideas, and to get this terms I need to learn about it.
People around me are non thinkers, they don't really argue about obvious things ! -I asked a friend what defines reality and he laughed with a ***funny eye looking***- 
And even my mind tells me that its useless to understand the learned philosophy because It won't help me in my field! 
To argue formally I need to learn  **the proper philosophy** But sadly from what I mentioned nowadays its totally useless if its not related directly with my own life's field.

Comment: What is your question? This post doesn't make sense, either.

Comment: The question is what do you think about what i said and is there any tips ?

Comment: That's not a suitable type of question for this site. See guidance here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: "*Is it useless to understand philosophy because it won't help me in my field?*"

For my tuppence worth, I would mention Heidegger's angle on inceptual thinking: thinking anew (a new beginning), in a self-actualised direction.  Self-actualised because of the appreciation of how reality is constructed primarily by the actor, with of course the influence of culture.  But culture can also be disempowering.  Inceptual thinking is about empowerment.

Recycling a quote from [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/79473/so-what-if-the-nature-of-dasein-is-being-in/79486#79486) quoting from *Contributions to Philosophy,* [*The human being and Da-sein*](https://books.google.gg/books?id=nMupXLZd8s4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA251#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 16:

> In this manner the inceptual meditation of thought necessarily becomes
> genuine thought, which is to say, *goal*-positing thought. ...
>
> To be *seeker, preserver, steward* -- that is what is meant by *care*
> as the fundamental trait of Dasein. These names for care gather
> together the destiny of humans as grasped in terms of their ground,
> i.e., in terms of Da-sein.  Da-sein, in turning, is ap-propriated to
> the *event* as the essence of beyng, and only in virtue of this origin
> as the grounding of time-space ("primordial temporality") can Da-sein
> become steadfast in order to transform the plight of the abandonment by
> being into the necessity of creating as the restoring of being.